# "VCE not responding, trying to reset the ECPU" presented at boot

Tags: boot, radeon, error-handling, syslog

When booting, I see the errors below. I have an HP laptop with an AMD CPU. I can link the model number if that would be useful. Given that it mentions Radeon, I'm assuming this has something to do with my onboard graphics and drivers?

```
> Oct  7 17:52:59 Greeneyes kernel: [    3.107408] [drm:vce_v1_0_start
> [radeon]] *ERROR* VCE not responding, trying to reset the ECPU!!! Oct 
> 7 17:52:59 Greeneyes kernel: [    4.125251] [drm:vce_v1_0_start
> [radeon]] *ERROR* VCE not responding, trying to reset the ECPU!!! Oct 
> 7 17:52:59 Greeneyes kernel: [    5.144342] [drm:vce_v1_0_start
> [radeon]] *ERROR* VCE not responding, trying to reset the ECPU!!! Oct 
> 7 17:52:59 Greeneyes kernel: [    6.163434] [drm:vce_v1_0_start
> [radeon]] *ERROR* VCE not responding, trying to reset the ECPU!!! Oct 
> 7 17:52:59 Greeneyes kernel: [    7.182525] [drm:vce_v1_0_start
> [radeon]] *ERROR* VCE not responding, trying to reset the ECPU!!! Oct 
> 7 17:52:59 Greeneyes kernel: [    8.201618] [drm:vce_v1_0_start
> [radeon]] *ERROR* VCE not responding, trying to reset the ECPU!!! Oct 
> 7 17:52:59 Greeneyes kernel: [    9.220710] [drm:vce_v1_0_start
> [radeon]] *ERROR* VCE not responding, trying to reset the ECPU!!! Oct 
> 7 17:52:59 Greeneyes kernel: [   10.239801] [drm:vce_v1_0_start
> [radeon]] *ERROR* VCE not responding, trying to reset the ECPU!!! Oct 
> 7 17:52:59 Greeneyes kernel: [   11.258893] [drm:vce_v1_0_start
> [radeon]] *ERROR* VCE not responding, trying to reset the ECPU!!! Oct 
> 7 17:52:59 Greeneyes kernel: [   12.277986] [drm:vce_v1_0_start
> [radeon]] *ERROR* VCE not responding, trying to reset the ECPU!!! Oct 
> 7 17:52:59 Greeneyes kernel: [   12.297968] [drm:vce_v1_0_start
> [radeon]] *ERROR* VCE not responding, giving up!!! Oct  7 17:52:59
> Greeneyes kernel: [   12.298013] [drm:cayman_startup [radeon]] *ERROR*
> radeon: failed initializing VCE (-1).
```

Comment: Does Ubuntu still boot afterward or does it just hang here?

Comment: @Zacharee1 It still boots and works normally, so it doesn't appear to be a very serious error?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it for now then